# Unusual CollectionView moveItem behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

So I have a very simple CollectionView with 4 items. I have implemented the CollectionView drag and drop reorder-functions initiated by a long-press gesture. It all works well apart from a problem where if I move an item and hover it over the destination index path (say for over 1 second) then dropped the cell, it is completely reset - all saved data / image etc is gone. If you move and drag an item quickly (say 0.5 seconds or less) this does not happen. Has anyone else experienced this? Tested and the issue is on my device as well as the simulator.

'

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
//      If a previous cell is free this logic will automitically select that one otherwise fallsback and selects the cell actually selected.
        for i in (0..<indexPath.item) {

        let x = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)) as! PickImageCollectionViewCell
            if(x.is_image_set == false) {
                x.selectImage()
                return
            }
        }
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PickImageCollectionViewCell
        cell.selectImage()
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerCellId", for: indexPath) as? SectionHeader {
            sectionHeader.label.text = "Images"
            sectionHeader.label.sizeToFit()
            sectionHeader.label.font = UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 22)
            sectionHeader.label.frame.origin.x = 10
//            sectionHeader.backgroundColor = .blue
            return sectionHeader
        }
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
    {

        return CGSize(width:screenSize.width, height: 40)
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    { return leftAndRightPaddings }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    { return leftAndRightPaddings }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 4
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PickImageCollectionViewCell

        if(cell.is_image_set == true) {
            cell.image_view.image = cell.image
        }

        cell.image_view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = (self.frame.width)/numberOfItemsPerRow - 20
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PickImageCollectionViewCell

        if (cell.is_image_set == true) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func reorderCells() {
        let items = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

        for i in (1..<items) {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)) as! PickImageCollectionViewCell
            let prev_cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i-1, section: 0)) as! PickImageCollectionViewCell
//            let next_cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: i+1, section: 0)) as! PickImageCollectionViewCell

            if(cell.is_image_set == true && prev_cell.is_image_set == false) {
                collectionView.moveItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0), to: IndexPath(item: i-1, section: 0))
                //Better solution when possible
                reorderCells()
            }
        }
    }

 @objc func longPressAction(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)  {

        switch(gesture.state) {
        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            print("BEGUN")
            print(selectedIndexPath)
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        case .changed:
            var loc = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
//            if (loc.x >= frame.maxX - 40) { loc.x = frame.maxX - 40 }
            collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(loc)
        case .ended:
            collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: { self.reorderCells() })
        default:
            collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
```

'

Comment: Can you post your drag and drop code and your cell code?

Comment: Sorry, just updated.

Comment: Why don't you use Apple's Drag and Drop API? Just curious.

Comment: Also, why are you calling reorderCells inside of reorderCells? The way to implement this is to swap your cells in the changed state and in the ended state.

Comment: Because at this point I tried side-stepping the Drag and Drop 'MovieItemAt' function to see if that was the cause, Which it wasn't so I will be returning to using that. Calling reorderCells inside itself I'm sure is dreadful programming practice but I couldn't get it to work any other way.